# Excel Macro error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Error]
[image: Code Highlighted]

Hi all can you take a look and let me know why I may be receiving this "Invalid procedure call or argument error?

I have researched similar problems and not found a solution.
Please assist with this question.

Comment: Start by removing `Version:=8` and `DefaultVersion:=8`.

Comment: Btw, your `TableDestination` appears to be on `Sheet30`, but the code immediately following selects `Sheet1`.

Comment: Pivottable1 could also be an issue

Comment: Confirm that you don't already have a pivot table named "PivotTable1" and that your destination cells are all blank.